# Using Word Editor to modify inbox email in Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am facing a situation where I can use Word Editor to modify the contents of an open inbox(active explorer).

I know to use word editor for compose window, but is there a way to access the body of the email thorough word editor.

Code for using Word Editor in Compose Window.

```
public void Click(Office.IRibbonControl Control)

{

 Outlook.Inspector uiInspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();

 object uiObject = uiInspector.CurrentItem;

 if (uiObject is Outlook.MailItem && uiInspector.IsWordMail())

 {

  Outlook.MailItem uiItem = (Outlook.MailItem)uiObject;

  Word.Document uiDoc = uiInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;

  if (uiDoc != null)

 {

 Word.Find uiFind = uiDoc.Range().Find;

 uiFind.Text = "ASA^$^$^#^#^#^#^#";

 while (uiFind.Execute())

 {

  var rng = uiFind.Parent as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range;

  rng.Hyperlinks.Add(rng, "http://stack.com=" + rng.Text + "outlook2007");

  rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);

 }

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

May be it is too late to answer here, but it will help other developer who got into same problem as I was.

**How to add word document text into Outlook compose email ?**

let suppose you have a Word document some where in your directory and want to fill your compose email with the document text.

Here I just modified your Click event

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

public void Click(Office.IRibbonControl Control)
{
    string documentPath = @"C:\\Documents";
    Outlook.Inspector = OutlookApp.ActiveInspector();
    Document we = inspector.WordEditor as Document;
    Find wf = we.Range().Find;
    wf.Application.Selection.Range.ImportFragment(documentPath);    
}
```